# Any difference between "travel through" and "travel around"?

Tags: word-choice

1. I traveled trough the UK last year.
2. I traveled around the UK last year.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: As a reminder, questions on Stack Exchange should provide adequate context, and should demonstrate your initial attempts at research. What do you think is the difference between the two, if any? Have you found examples, for example, from a web search that cause you to question your assumption?

Answer (score 2):

To **travel around [a place]** means you spend time in that place looking at it and make some kind of tour of it.

To **travel through [a place]** means you go to it because it is between your origin and your destination.

- I **travelled through** the UK last year on my way to Ireland from France.
- I **travelled around** the UK last year.  I went to Yorkshire, East Anglia, Kent, Sussex, Hampshire and Cornwall.
- (More rare) I **travelled around** Cuba last year [*in my boat*].  I **travelled around** London [to *avoid the congestion*].  Means travelled along the perimeter (eg by boat) or avoiding entering (perhaps by a large amount).  (Thanks commenter).

Comment: many thanks! It's really hard.

Comment: Note that "travel around" could rarely mean to literally go around it, but that is usually made clear by the context. "We travelled around London to avoid the congestion charge." "I travelled all the way around the world."

Comment: @Showsni thanks, added to answer